# Upload video to vimeo server from my website (developed in CodeIgniter 3)

Tags: codeigniter-3, vimeo, vimeo-api

First I upload the video in my web server. Then i want to transfer the video to vimeo server.I have downloaded the code from vimeo given github URL (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php). Using composer update the code. After that I am trying to create a custom library for CodeIgniter. In application/libraries folder put all files including 'vimeo.php' for library and in 'autoload.php' page under the 'application/config' folder set `$autoload['libraries']=array('vimeo');`. Now I call the library from controller

```
$lib = new Vimeo(); 
$video_url=base_url().''.$directory.''.$data['video_name'];
$uri = $lib->upload($video_url);
$video_data = $lib->request($uri);
$film_video = $lib->request('/ondemand/pages/myfilm'.$video_data['body']['uri'], array('type' => 'main'), 'PUT');
```

It shows error. The error is as follows:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: VimeoUploadException
Message: Unable to locate file to upload.
```

I have checked the video file is present in the '$video_url' path.Could any one help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: `$video_url = FCPATH . $directory . $data['video_name'];`. If `$directory` does not start or end with slash add some between.

Comment: @Tpojka,Thanks lot.

Comment: Enjoy your code. #soreadytohelp

Comment: @Tpojka, recently I have received the error in vimeo. It shows following error. 
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: VimeoUploadException
Message: Unable to get an upload ticket.
How to solve this problem.

Comment: Is it set upload scope for Vimeo app?